# Ng-repeat in groups | AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have data,something like this (its come from SWARM,backend) :

```
$scope.games = [
  {"categories":["1"],"id":"id1"},
  {"categories":["1"],"id":"id2"},
  {"categories":["1"],"id":"id3"},
  {"categories":["1"],"id":"id4"},
  {"categories":["2"],"id":"id5"},
  {"categories":["2"],"id":"id6"},
  {"categories":["2"],"id":"id7"},
  {"categories":["3"],"id":"id8"},
  {"categories":["3"],"id":"id9"}
  {"categories":["4"],"id":"id10"}
];
```

So, now its visible in content without any category grouping , like

```
id1 id2 id3 id4 id5 id6 id7 id8 id9 id10
```

But i need to do:

```
Category '1'
id1 id2 id3 id4

Category '2'
id5 id6 id7 

Category '3'
id8 id9 

Category '4'
id10
```

HTML source:

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="game in games by game.id">
     ...               
  </li>
</ul>
```

Any ideas how ?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: you can create you own groupBy filter or use https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter#groupby. I actually just used this to group some items by date

Comment: Looks like something great.

Answer (score 0):

Why not make the date structured a bit?
For (a simplest) example:

```
$scope.games = {
  "1": ["id1", "id2", "id3", "id4"],
  "2": ["id5", "id6", "id7"]
}
```

... and so on.

Comment: I cant do that , data came from backend from another country

Comment: to add to this, you could preprocess the data and ng-repeat the preprocessed data

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(categories, catGames) in (games | groupBy: 
         'categories')">
    {{categories}}
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="game in catGames">
        {{game.id}}
        </li>
    </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: There is no `groupBy` built into angular core

Comment: What is catGames ?

Comment: First of all, I forgot to mention to that you have to use an external api [angular-filter](https://github.com/a8m/angular-filter). Second, catGames in that example is a the list of games for a for a specific category, and for every category it creates such a list.